# How to create js object from pairs of dynamic inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got pretty messy with it and can't find a way to do this right.
I have a button, that creates pair of inputs, one is the type and the other is "value".

I want to gather up their text values into neat little object for further processing.But it's not important. This is how it looks:
[image]

And this here is what I got so far

```
 try {
        var typy = {};
        var wartosc;
        var arrtypow = [];
        $('.atribinput').each(function () {

                if ($('.atribtext').hasClass('select2-offscreen')) {
                    wartosc = $(this).select2('data')['text'];
                } else {
                    wartosc = $(this).val();
                }


                 typy = {
                      typ:$('.atribtype').select2('data')['text'],
                      wartosc:wartosc
                 };

            }
        );
        console.log(typy);
    }
    catch(err) {
        return null;
    }
```

But it returns strange stuff like:

```
Object { typ: "Data otrzymania", wartosc: text() }
```

I honestly have no idea what's wrong and how can I do it and if it's possible.

Oh yeah and classes: .atribinput is all dynamic inputs (left and right), .atribtext are right ones and .atribtype left ones. Maybe it's becouse they share the one class?

EDIT:

As requested I add HTML markup.

```
<div class="form-group attribBoxes">
<div class="attribBox">
    <input name="data[ProjectAttribute][0][project_attribute_type_id]" value="2" id="ProjectAttribute0ProjectAttributeTypeId" type="hidden">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ProjectAttribute0Value" class="col-md-4 control-label">Data otrzymania</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input name="data[ProjectAttribute][0][value]" class="form-control summarytrigger required datepicker" empty="Wpisz wartość " id="ProjectAttribute0Value" data-validate="required" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="attribBox">
    <input name="data[ProjectAttribute][1][project_attribute_type_id]" value="3" id="ProjectAttribute1ProjectAttributeTypeId" type="hidden">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ProjectAttribute1Value" class="col-md-4 control-label">Termin odpowiedzi</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input name="data[ProjectAttribute][1][value]" class="form-control summarytrigger required datepicker" empty="Wpisz wartość " id="ProjectAttribute1Value" data-validate="required" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="attribBox">
    <div class="inputdefault3" style="display: none">
        <input name="data[ProjectAttribute][3][value]" class="form-control summarytrigger atribinput atribtext required" empty="Wpisz wartość " id="ProjectAttribute2Value" data-validate="required" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12" style="margin-left: 8%">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="select2-container projectattributetypeid3 atribinput summarytrigger atribtype" id="s2id_autogen9">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return false;" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1"> <span class="select2-chosen">Data otrzymania</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr> <span class="select2-arrow"><b></b></span></a>
                    <input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" id="s2id_autogen10" type="text">
                </div>
                <input name="data[ProjectAttribute][3][project_attribute_type_id]" class="projectattributetypeid3 atribinput summarytrigger atribtype select2-offscreen" tabindex="-1" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left: 4%" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 inputchange3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="data[ProjectAttribute][3][value]" class="form-control summarytrigger atribinput atribtext required datepicker" empty="Wpisz wartość " id="ProjectAttribute2Value" data-validate="required" type="text"> </div>
        </div><a style="margin-left: 2%; margin-top: 5px;" class="btn btn-danger removeatributesrow">-</a></div>
</div>
<div class="attribBox">
    <div class="inputdefault4" style="display: none">
        <input name="data[ProjectAttribute][4][value]" class="form-control summarytrigger atribinput atribtext required" empty="Wpisz wartość " id="ProjectAttribute2Value" data-validate="required" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12" style="margin-left: 8%">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="select2-container projectattributetypeid4 atribinput summarytrigger atribtype" id="s2id_autogen11">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return false;" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1"> <span class="select2-chosen">Województwo</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr> <span class="select2-arrow"><b></b></span></a>
                    <input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" id="s2id_autogen12" type="text">
                </div>
                <input name="data[ProjectAttribute][4][project_attribute_type_id]" class="projectattributetypeid4 atribinput summarytrigger atribtype select2-offscreen" tabindex="-1" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left: 4%" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 inputchange4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="select2-container atribtext form-control required" id="s2id_ProjectAttribute4Value">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return false;" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1"> <span class="select2-chosen">Podkarpackie</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr> <span class="select2-arrow"><b></b></span></a>
                    <input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" id="s2id_autogen17" type="text">
                </div>
                <select id="ProjectAttribute4Value" class="atribtext form-control required select2-offscreen" name="data[ProjectAttribute][4][project_attribute_type_dicts_id]" data-validate="required" tabindex="-1">
                    <option value="">-- Wybierz z listy ---</option>
                    <option value="2">Małopolska</option>
                    <option value="3">Podkarpackie</option>
                    <option value="4">Śląskie</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div><a style="margin-left: 2%; margin-top: 5px;" class="btn btn-danger removeatributesrow">-</a></div>
</div>
<div class="attribBox">
    <div class="inputdefault5" style="display: none">
        <input name="data[ProjectAttribute][5][value]" class="form-control summarytrigger atribinput atribtext required" empty="Wpisz wartość " id="ProjectAttribute2Value" data-validate="required" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12" style="margin-left: 8%">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="select2-container projectattributetypeid5 atribinput summarytrigger atribtype" id="s2id_autogen13">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return false;" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1"> <span class="select2-chosen">Zainteresowania</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr> <span class="select2-arrow"><b></b></span></a>
                    <input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" id="s2id_autogen14" type="text">
                </div>
                <input name="data[ProjectAttribute][5][project_attribute_type_id]" class="projectattributetypeid5 atribinput summarytrigger atribtype select2-offscreen" tabindex="-1" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left: 4%" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 inputchange5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="select2-container atribtext form-control required" id="s2id_ProjectAttribute5Value">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return false;" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1"> <span class="select2-chosen">Muzyka</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr> <span class="select2-arrow"><b></b></span></a>
                    <input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" id="s2id_autogen18" type="text">
                </div>
                <select id="ProjectAttribute5Value" class="atribtext form-control required select2-offscreen" name="data[ProjectAttribute][5][project_attribute_type_dicts_id]" data-validate="required" tabindex="-1">
                    <option value="">-- Wybierz z listy ---</option>
                    <option value="5">Muzyka</option>
                    <option value="6">Sport</option>
                    <option value="7">Kino</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div><a style="margin-left: 2%; margin-top: 5px;" class="btn btn-danger removeatributesrow">-</a></div>
</div>
<div class="attribBox">
    <div class="inputdefault6" style="display: none">
        <input name="data[ProjectAttribute][6][value]" class="form-control summarytrigger atribinput atribtext required" empty="Wpisz wartość " id="ProjectAttribute2Value" data-validate="required" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12" style="margin-left: 8%">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="select2-container projectattributetypeid6 atribinput summarytrigger atribtype" id="s2id_autogen15">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return false;" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1"> <span class="select2-chosen">Pilna data</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr> <span class="select2-arrow"><b></b></span></a>
                    <input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" id="s2id_autogen16" type="text">
                </div>
                <input name="data[ProjectAttribute][6][project_attribute_type_id]" class="projectattributetypeid6 atribinput summarytrigger atribtype select2-offscreen" tabindex="-1" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left: 4%" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 inputchange6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="data[ProjectAttribute][6][value]" class="form-control summarytrigger atribinput atribtext required datepicker" empty="Wpisz wartość " id="ProjectAttribute2Value" data-validate="required" type="text"> </div>
        </div><a style="margin-left: 2%; margin-top: 5px;" class="btn btn-danger removeatributesrow">-</a></div>
</div>
```

As you see, I want to get value on the left as key and value on the right as a value in array or object or array of objects.

Plsease help if can do.

Comment: Post the HTML as we can only assume the markup. But if `.atribinput` is the parent of `.atribtext` and `.atribtype` then you should really add the context `this` as second argument of `$('.atribtext')` and `$('.atribtype')` as otherwise it will query and find ALL the elements with that class on the page, not the one that are contain within the input class. But like I said I'm just assuming the HTML as it wasn't posted.

Comment: Do post the html and the desired output. I think you need an array of objects. One for each pair. And what are `.select2` methods?

Comment: Sorry for being late. I added requested html. And I think you are right, array of objects would be great. And .select2 is Select2 js script for quite advanced selects. I just don't know how to build array of objects from this stuff.